# My attempt to solve the full permutation problem with a character array got "output limit exceeeded", and I succeeded with a string

Tags: c++

### Description

You are to write a program that has to generate all possible words from a given set of letters.
Example: Given the word "abc", your program should - by exploring all different combination of the three letters - output the words "abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab" and "cba".
In the word taken from the input file, some letters may appear more than once. For a given word, your program should not produce the same word more than once, and the words should be output in alphabetically ascending order.

### Input

The input consists of several words. The first line contains a number giving the number of words to follow. Each following line contains one word. A word consists of uppercase or lowercase letters from A to Z. Uppercase and lowercase letters are to be considered different. The length of each word is less than 13.

### Output

For each word in the input, the output should contain all different words that can be generated with the letters of the given word. The words generated from the same input word should be output in alphabetically ascending order. An upper case letter goes before the corresponding lower case letter.

## Here are the code which used character array and got "output limit exceeeded"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
bool cmp(char a, char b)
{
    double aa = a;
    double bb = b;
    double d = 'a' - 'A' - 0.5;
    if (aa >= 'a')
    {
        aa = a - d;
    }
    if (bb >= 'a')
    {
        bb = b - d;
    }
    return aa < bb;
}
void swap(char *s, int a, int b)
{
    int t = s[a];
    s[a] = s[b];
    s[b] = t;
}
void permutation(char *s, int m, int n)
{
    if (m == n)
    {
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
    else
    {
        char t[100];
        for (int i = m; i < n + 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == m)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++)
                {
                    t[j] = s[j];
                }
            }
//prevent dumplication
            if (i != m && s[i] == s[m])
            {
                continue;
            }

            swap(s, i, m);
            permutation(s, m + 1, n);
            if (i == n)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++)
                {
                    s[j] = t[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    while (n--)
    {
        char s[100];
        cin >> s;
        int lenth = strlen(s);
        sort(s, s + lenth, cmp);
        permutation(s, 0, lenth - 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## Here are the code which used string and was accepted

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
void swap(string &s, int a, int b)
{
    char t = s[a];
    s[a] = s[b];
    s[b] = t;
}
bool cmp(char a, char b)
{
    double aa = a;
    double bb = b;
    double d = 'a' - 'A' - 0.5;
    if (aa >= 'a')
    {
        aa = a - d;
    }
    if (bb >= 'a')
    {
        bb = b - d;
    }
    return aa < bb;
}
void permutation(string s, int m, int n)
{
    if (m == n)
    {
        cout << s;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = m; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (i != m && s[i] == s[m])
            {
                continue;
            }
            swap(s, i, m);
            permutation(s, m + 1, n);
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string str;
        cin >> str;
        sort(str.begin(), str.end(), cmp);
        permutation(str, 0, str.size() - 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to use string which was transferred by character array to give an output or  got an input with string then transfer to character array,but all of them got "output limit exceeded". Then I think that maybe the size of the character array was small (although the problem said one word is less than 13), so I state the array with 10000 size, then I got wrong answer.
I just want to use character array to solve the problem.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to NUL-terminate your character arrays.

Comment: @n.m. Do you mean like this?But it still dosen't work.The change that I made in function permutation:~~~        char t[100];
        t[m + 1] = '\n';~~~and the change that I made in function main:~~~char s[100];
        cin >> s;
        int lenth = strlen(s);
        s[lenth] = '\0';~~~

Comment: No these changes are wrong. `\n` has nothing to do with it (should be 0) and changes in main are not needed.

Comment: @n.m.First of all,thanks for your comment.After reading your comment, I made a try that I don't change the function main and change the statement of character array t in functon permutation like this :<pre>        char t[100];
        t[n + 1] = '\0';<code>but it dosen't work.I still got output limit exceeded.

Comment: There is [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) which does the job [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PTdK1TWfb).

Comment: Maybe there are other errors. Did you try to test it yourself?

Comment: I apologize, I did not read your program carefully enough. My previous comments are incorrect. You don't nul-terminate t, but it is not needed, t is just a character array, not a string. s is a string but it is nul-terminated and is kept this way. The problem is elsewhere. Try to permute two strings `aaaX` and `aaaA` and you will see what happens.

Comment: @Jarod42 A custom comparator is needed to satisfy the requirements but otherwise yes, it does. Probably. Depending on what you consider a job done.

Comment: @n.m.: In ASCII, upper is before lower, so default comp is OK (For EBCDIC, it is not). `[](unsigned char lhs, unsigned char rhs){ return std::tuple(std::islower(lhs, lhs)) < std::tuple(std::islower(rhs, rhs)); }` would be the comparer.

Comment: @Jarod42 Upper should come *immediately* before lower.

Comment: @n.m.I don't know how to express my gratefulness.I have been stuck with this problem for a long time.I'm afraid I'll still be stuck with this problem without your help.How clever and kind you are!Wish you all the best!

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for comment.I know that I can solve this problem by using the function in std with a customized comparison functon,but I want to solve this problem by using a function that written by myself.This will let me know the function better and improve my coding  ability.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @n.m..It is he who point out my mistake.I find that in the loop of the function permutation,if i==n and i!=m and s[i]==s[m],the loop will terminates directly and won't made the character array "s" back to the condition when it first got into the loop.
Here are the Acceped answer.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstring>
    using namespace std;
    bool cmp(char a, char b)
    {
        double aa = a;
        double bb = b;
        double d = 'a' - 'A' - 0.5;
        if (aa >= 'a')
        {
            aa = a - d;
        }
        if (bb >= 'a')
        {
            bb = b - d;
        }
        return aa < bb;
    }
    void swap(char *s, int a, int b)
    {
        int t = s[a];
        s[a] = s[b];
        s[b] = t;
    }
    void mycopy(char *a, char *b, int size)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            a[j] = b[j];
        }
    }
    void permutation(char *s, int m, int n)
    {
        if (m == n)
        {
            printf("%s\n", s);
        }
        else
        {
            char t[100];
            for (int i = m; i < n + 1; i++)
            {
                if (i == m)
                {
                    mycopy(t, s, n + 1);
                }
                if (i == n && i != m && s[i] == s[m])
                {
                    mycopy(s, t, n + 1);
                    continue;
                }
                if (i != m && s[i] == s[m])
                {
                    continue;
                }
                swap(s, i, m);
                permutation(s, m + 1, n);
                if (i == n)
                {
                    mycopy(s, t, n + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        while (n--)
        {
            char s[100];
            cin >> s;
            int lenth = strlen(s);
            sort(s, s + lenth, cmp);
            permutation(s, 0, lenth - 1);
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

This tells us that we should be careful when we used continue and something like it(such as break).